# folder permissions docker-osx-dev

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I'm using docker on macOS with docker-osx-dev (https://github.com/brikis98/docker-osx-dev)
And all is ok. It helps me to solve the problem with slow volumes. But every time when i up my docker-compose i have a problem with permissions and i am forced to set permission through docker exec and chmod ... I spent a lot of time to find solution. I tried to use usermod with 501 and 1000 id but nothing help. Have you any idea about how to fix it?
My project settings: https://bitbucket.org/SmileSergey/symfonydocker/src
Thanks!

Comment: Please share specific issues/errors and maybe add some code snippets to your question. Linking BitBucket is not enough to get an answer

Comment: i have default symfony error with file permissions:
 Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Failed to write cache file "/var/www/symfony/var/cache/dev/classes.php". in /var/www/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/ClassCollectionLoader.php:248
After that i do:
docker exec -ti symfonydefault_php_1 bash
chmod -R 777 /var/www/symfony/
and all is fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://docker-sync.io with the https://github.com/EugenMayer/docker-sync/blob/master/example/docker-sync.yml#L47 to map the OSX user to the uid you have on the container. This removes the whole issue, even though this will replace docker-osx-dev completely.

Comment: thx, i will try it in future. Now after i spent my weekends for trying to use docker on OSX i solve all of my problems by using docker in vagrant and nfs shared folders. Yes its funny docker in vagrant but for dev it works nice ;)

Answer (score 0):

As a quick workaround, you could try to add a command to your nginx part of [your docker-compose.yml](https://bitbucket.org/SmileSergey/symfonydocker/src/cd21ff2786c74c826bd2f242577ad150e242fa02/docker-compose.yml?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) like follows:

```
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ...
    volumes:
      - "./config/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
      - "./app:/var/www/symfony"
    command: /bin/bash -c "chmod -R 777 /var/www/symfony/ && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```

**Background:**

the official [nginx Dockerfile](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/master/mainline/jessie/Dockerfile) specifies following default command:

```
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

which is executing

```
nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

You already have found a quick&dirty workaround to run `chmod -R 777 /var/www/symfony/` within the container.

With the command in the docker-compose file above, we execute the `chmod` command before executing the `nginx -g 'daemon off;'` default command.

Note, that a `CMD` specified in the Dockerfile is replaced by the command defined on a docker-compose file (or any command specified on `docker run ... myimage mycommand`.)

Answer (score -2):

For dev on OSX just use vagrant + nfs shared folders. It solves whole the problems and doesn't require to add anything special to docker-compose for dev.

Comment: While this is viable alternative, it does not answer the question.